# Вывести права доступа к файлам в восьмиричный системе

Tags: linux

Надо вывести список всего, что в директории, только чтобы права доступа файлов были не в символьном обозначении, а в восьмиричный системе счисления.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

например, можно воспользоваться программой *stat*:

```
$ stat --printf='%a %n\n' *
777 file1
644 file2
1777 file3
```

подробнее — [`man stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat)